# Does a subclass need to initialize an empty super class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This just came into my mind.

```
class Parent:
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # is this necessary?
        super().__init__()
```

When a class inherits an empty class, do the subclass need to initialize it and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just fine:

```
class Parent:
    # the __init__ is inherited from parent
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    # the __init__ is inherited from parent
    pass
```

This is also fine:

```
class Parent:
    # the __init__ is inherited from parent
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # __init__ is called on parent
        super().__init__()
```

This may seem ok, and will usually work fine, but not always:

```
class Parent:
    # the __init__ is inherited from parent
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # this does not call parent's __init__, 
        pass
```

Here is one example where it goes wrong:

```
class Parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Parent2 initialized')


class Child2(Child, Parent2):
    pass

# you'd expect this to call Parent2.__init__, but it won't:
Child2()
```

This is because the MRO of `Child2` is: Child2 -> Child -> Parent -> Parent2 -> object.

`Child2.__init__` is inherited from `Child` and that one does not call `Parent2.__init__`, because of the missing call to `super().__init__`.

Comment: Oh-ho!  So you not only need the init of the class you are inheriting from to be empty - you also need the init of every base class of classes that inherit *from* you to be empty - tricky!

Comment: @MartinBonner If all classes which implement `__init__` also call `super().__init__`, then everything is fine. Then again, you run into deeper problems if the `__init__` of each class takes different arguments, but that is a different story...

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't necessary. It is necessary when you want the parent's logic to run as well.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_field = 'value'    

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_field = 'other_value'
        super().__init__()
child = Child()
child.some_field # 'value'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement in the language that subclass need to call `__init__` of superclass. Despite this, it is almost always needed because superclass initializes some base attributes and the subclass expects them to be initialized. So, if the superclass `__init__` is empty, you don't need to call it, otherwise you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation of the super() function and its usability (as I got it)
it helps to initiate parent class without knowing its name e.g. super().`__init__`() inside child class constructor.
**if child class has it's own constructor then the parent class initialization is needed** to allow child class's objects to get parent class's instance variables and parent class's methods. **On the contrary, the parent class initialization is not needed if child class does not have its own constructor.** This way parent class's variables and method will be accessible for the object instantiated from child class.
if used then `__init__`() goes w/o 'self' parameter, and if parent accepts other arguments they needs to be passed:  super().`__init__`(var1, var2, ...)
as alternative if parent's class name is known or wants to be used explicitly: ParentClassName.`__init__`(self, var1, var2, ...)

**So, if the parent class does not have any variable or method (or there is no plan to invoke/address them from child's class object) then there is no reason to initialize it in child class, unless it will be modified in future and you forgot to initialize it inside child class.**